# Way to interrupt method to get additional input from user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working in ASP.net Core and have a situation where I'm importing a large list of swimming results from a previous meet. The list contains swimmer name and location so I'm doing a lookup to find that swimmerID in the database which I have previously imported. HOWEVER, I've found that many of the previous sheets have names misspelled or names that were not included in my original import.

I'm looking for a way to change the below code:

```
//Get SwimmerId and check for an existing entry in the db
var swimmerId = await _swimmerRepo.GetSwimmerByNameAndLocation(lookupObj.FirstName,
                    lookupObj.LastName,
                    lookupObj.LocationCode);

if (swimmerId == 0) throw new Exception($"Swimmer {lookupObj.LocationCode}: {lookupObj.FirstName} {lookupObj.LastName} not found.");
```

**What I really want to do here instead of throwing an exception is to popup a modal or whatever to the user that allows them to choose from a swimmer that has a similar name/location (possible spelling error) or enter a new swimmer and then push that selected/new swimmerId back and continue processing the import.**

I have no idea how I can do that. Any direction is appreciated.

*A few notes:
Again, asp.net core with EFCore.
SQL server database
Import is currently in a controller
Import is from a csv file*

Comment: In ASP you'd have to render a new page that tells the user to update their inputs.  Possible but not as simple as "popping up a modal dialog" like a windows app could.

Comment: So something like `return View("SwimmerNotFound");`? But how do I come back to the same place where I left the import and return an int to that process?

Comment: @Wyatt you don't; rather you design it such that you can present all the problems on one page, and try to submit from there; or alternatively: show all the problems and deal with them as the user does things via AJAX

Comment: What Marc said - you could have some AJAX calls to look for invalid data before submitting the entire page, or render a new page and start the process all over.  ASP.NET is stateless at its core - each time you submit the page it's a brand new request.

Comment: Ok guys. Very helpful thank you!